# How to consume a stand alone application installed on azure server through Ajax request

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, azure, iis, web-hosting

I have one web app hosted on some server "www.example.com". Now on the same server I am running one application which is listening request at lets say "https://xyz.example.com" (co-domain).

Both of the above domains are pointing to the same IP. Now from my web site I want to send post call to my app which is running on "https://xyz.example.com".

Now when I try to do a Ajax post with url "https://xyz.example.com", I get 404 error. As per my understanding the app is not available on given co-domain "https://xyz.example.com".

Do I need to configure IIS binding for this app also (which is present on "https://xyz.example.com")?

In short I want to consume my application (stand alone app) which is installed on server from Ajax request.

I've hosted my MVC app and standalone app on azure on same server.